# stuck; SQL case statement with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on a problem and I am hoping that you guys can help.

I am running mySQL with XAMPP and PHP My Admin (PMA)

I have two tables:

Table A

```
A          |B
1000000001 |100000001
1000000001 |100000002
1000000001 |100000003
1000000002 |100000004
1000000002 |100000005
1000000003 |100000006
```

Table B

```
C         |D
1000000001|100000000000001
1000000002|100000000000002
1000000003|100000000000003
1000000004|100000000000004
1000000005|100000000000005
1000000006|100000000000006
```

I have joined the two tables to represent the following:

```
A        |B/C       |D
100000001|1000000001|100000000000001
100000001|1000000002|100000000000002
100000001|1000000003|100000000000003
100000002|1000000004|100000000000004
100000002|1000000005|100000000000005
100000003|1000000006|100000000000006
```

Notice the pattern that occurs in the first three data points.

Essentially I need help understanding how to write a case script That would return a unique A value and the Count of the D value per A value

The Return would be:

```
A        |D_COUNT
100000001|3
100000001|2
100000003|1
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't do that with `CASE`. You do that with [`GROUP BY`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm).

Comment: That's not very hard to achieve. What have you tried?

Comment: I guess I am having the most trouble with the syntax? again PHPMyAdmin. Or do I even need a case statement?

Comment: Is your output correct? Look at the 1st & 2nd row of column A in the output

Comment: Could the same problem be illustrated with fewer zeros?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A,
       COUNT(DISTINCT D) AS count_d
FROM table_c
GROUP BY A;
```

Answer (score 1):

The tables you give seems to be a bit of a mistake,the length of TableA.B is 9 and TableB.C is 10 ,ignore this,you may write your query string like this:

```
select A,count(A) as D_COUNT 
from t_a,t_b 
where t_a.b=t_b.c 
group by t_a.A;
```

TableA ==> t_a

TableB ==> t_b

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select A,count(A) as D_Count from tablename group by A
```